# TTL getting changed while pinging local network printer

Tags: windows-10, ping, tcp

When i'm pining a local device (NW printer) from win-10 PC using cmd, the TTL changing from 64 to 255 and again back to 64 continuously.

Kindly share the probable cause for this. see below..

```
Reply from 192.168.141.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=255
Reply from 192.168.141.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=255
Reply from 192.168.141.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=255
Reply from 192.168.141.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.141.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.141.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=255
Reply from 192.168.141.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.141.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=255
Reply from 192.168.141.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=255
Reply from 192.168.141.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=255
Reply from 192.168.141.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.141.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=255
Reply from 192.168.141.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=255
Reply from 192.168.141.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=255
Reply from 192.168.141.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=255
Reply from 192.168.141.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.141.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=255
Reply from 192.168.141.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.141.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
```

Comment: Could there be a second device with a duplicate IP address? If it's on the same local network as your PC, you can try checking whether `arp -a 192.168.141.10` shows any duplicates. Different operating systems use different starting values for TTL. Some devices use 255, while others use 64 or 128, and it's based on the system that is replying.

Comment: Disconnect the printer while pinging it. Do responses with a certain TTL keep coming?